# Go printing date to console

Tags: go

I'm trying to pint the month, day, and year, separately to the console.

I need to be able to access each section of the date individually. I can get the whole thing using `time.now()` from the "time" package but I'm stuck after that.

Can anyone show me where I am going wrong please?

Comment: Added in a way to print the month as an integer in case it is useful (apparently I forgot to submit the edit last night :) ).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're actually pretty close :) Then return value from `time.Now()` is a `Time` type, and looking at the package docs [here](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) will show you some of the methods you can call (for a quicker overview, go [here](http://golang.org/pkg/time/) and look under `type Time`). To get each of the attributes you mention above, you can do this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(t.Month())
    fmt.Println(t.Day())
    fmt.Println(t.Year())
}
```

If you are interested in printing the `Month` as an integer, you can use the `Printf` function:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", t.Month())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Day, Month and Year can be extracted from a [`time.Time`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) type with the [`Date()`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Date) method. It will return ints for both day and year, and a [`time.Month`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Month) for the month. You can also extract the Hour, Minute and Second values with the [`Clock()`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Clock) method, which returns ints for all results.

For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    y, mon, d := t.Date()
    h, m, s := t.Clock()
    fmt.Println("Year: ", y)
    fmt.Println("Month: ", mon)
    fmt.Println("Day: ", d)
    fmt.Println("Hour: ", h)
    fmt.Println("Minute: ", m)
    fmt.Println("Second: ", s)
}
```

Please remember that the Month variable (`mon`) is returned as a `time.Month`, and not as a string, or an int. You can still print it with `fmt.Print()` as it has a `String()` method.

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/vW51CCe755)

Comment: thank you both very much for the help. how do you convert the month to an int?

Comment: how do you return time.month as an integer? i have been playing around with this for a while and haven't gotten anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can just parse the string to get year, month, & day.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    currTime := time.Now()
    date := strings.Split(currTime.String(), " ")[0]
    splits := strings.Split(date, "-")
    year := splits[0]
    month := splits[1]
    day := splits[2]

    fmt.Printf("%s-%s-%s\n", year, month, day)
}
```